# How do i get app activity in background mode of ionic cordova app for 1 hour

Tags: ionic-framework, background, cordova-plugins

Background activity for almost an hour of ionic app

I have tried **background mode** plugin,**Background geolocation** plugin and platform.these plugins work in background mode but only for 5 to 6 minute if any one have answer please share.

Comment: You cant, it's a security issue.